# Ubuntu server as DHCP Server and Internet Gateway

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-11.04, dhcp-server

In my work environment there is one ubuntu server (dynamic ip) and 6 win7 systems all connected to a switch which is connected to a modem(isp internet). Right now the modem acts as dhcp server and assigns ip for all the systems including ubuntu server.

I wanted to use my ubuntu server as DHCP server and assign ip and provide internet all other win7 systems. What should i do inorder to make this kind of configuration ? I know many workspace and schools follow this configuration.

I know i have to install dhcp server in ubuntu but after that i have no idea about configuration. I have ordered for static ip only for my ubuntu server.

My question is can i make my ubuntu server as my internet gateway and provide internet access to all other systems so i can also install firewall in the server. What is the exact configuration please guide me. Right now ubuntu server has dynamic ip is it possible now ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Linux has *very* extensive network capabilities.

As for configuration, Ubuntu guides are quite good: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

I'd also recommend reading about Linux (Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide) and Linux System Administration (The Linux System Administrators' Guide) at http://tldp.org/guides.html to get a wider picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I would suggest looking at [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) for your DHCP and DNS requirements, and [Squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid) as your proxy server if required.